# Partial Derivatives using ChainRule

Tags: partial-derivative

Can any one please explain the second step:-

Step1:
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left[(1-x^2)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right]+\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left[y^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right]=0$$

Step2:
$$L.H.S.=-2x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+(1-x^2)\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial x^2}+2y\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+y^2\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial y^2}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with Step 1 we have:-
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left[1-x^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right]+\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left[y^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right]\\=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(1)-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial x})+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(y^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial y})$$

The first term of the above expression should be $0$ as we are differentiating a constant (the number $1$) with respect to $x$.  Applying the product rule for differentiation to the second and third terms, we obtain:-
$$0-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial x})+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(y^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial y})\\=-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x^2)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-x^2\frac{\partial^2u}{dx^2}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(y^2)\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+y^2\frac{\partial^2u}{dy^2}\\=-2x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-x^2\frac{\partial^2u}{dx^2}+2y\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+y^2\frac{\partial^2u}{dy^2}\\=\text{LHS}$$

Comment: Ok I understood the first part for second part Please correct me if am wrong...
By product rule you took  $$u=-\frac{\partial}{\partial x},v=x^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$$
$$\therefore u\frac{dv}{dx}+v\frac{du}{dx}$$
then how u have applied the rule for this in the second part

$$=-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x^2)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-x^2\frac{\partial^2u}{dx^2}$$

Comment: For the product rule, (I will use different variables to avoid confusion) I took $$a=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x},  b=-x^2$$ and $$\therefore a\frac{\partial b}{\partial x}+b\frac{\partial a}{\partial x}=-2x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-x^2\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$$.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure about the +1 after step 2? I think, that 1 is disappearing after derivation.

If you derive $-x^2\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}$ then you have to use the product rule.

$$u=-x^2$$
$$v=\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}$$
$$(u \cdot v)'=u'\cdot v+u\cdot v'$$